# Implement endless recyclerview -android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

so i'm trying to implement an endless recyclerview. I read other tutorials and samples on stack and none of them are straightforward. I'm looking for a universal answer that can be applied for a lot of people's needs including my own.

Currently, i have a recyclerview + adapter working that gets data from my backend and loads it. Now, when i reach the end I want to call my api methods to get data again and load it into my Recycler view.

Here is my Recycler view initialization.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_9b_newsfeed , container, false);
        bindActivity();
        return rootView;
    }
    private void bindActivity()
    {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_PB);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_RV);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        endlessScrollListener = new EndlessScrollListener()//no clue how the hell to use it.
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount)
            {
                //when i reach my last post, this doesn't even get called..so don't really know how to use this.
                return false;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(endlessScrollListener);

        GetPostsAsyncTask getPostsAsyncTask = new GetPostsAsyncTask();
        getPostsAsyncTask.execute();
    }
```

This is my GetPostAsyncTask class, which grabs my post data, encapsulates it into Post Objects, then shoves into my recyclerview, which displays the posts as a newsfeed like feature.

```
 private class GetPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            if(doesPostListExist)
            {
                getNewsFeed = new GetNewsFeed(getActivity(),true,Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().user.getUsername());
                getNewsFeed.getMyNewsFeed();
            }
            else
            {
                getNewsFeed = new GetNewsFeed(getActivity(),false,Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().user.getUsername());
                getNewsFeed.getMyNewsFeed();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            farTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
            Log.d(MY_NEWSFEED,"my far time is " + String.valueOf(farTime));

            if(getNewsFeed.isGetNewsFeedSuccess())
            {
                complexRecyclerViewAdapter = new ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(getNewsFeed.getNewsFeedPost());//change getNewsFeed.getNewsFeedPost() -> postArrayList
                recyclerView.setAdapter(complexRecyclerViewAdapter);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the endlessScrollListener Class, which i scrapped up somewhere, I have no idea how to use it, but here it is.

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; }
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) >= totalItemCount ) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

My adapter class is gigantic as hell, (to display all the UI), It may be confusing to read all that code. But assume you have a normal recyclerview adapter that handles an arraylist of strings as input, please write that down in your answer if there is anything I myself must put in my adapter in order for endless scrolling to work.

Overall, im looking for a complete easy and functional solution for this universal problem.

thanks!

Comment: It seems you have all you need. You just have to put all together all the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems a little overly complicated.  Using a scroll listener at all is unneeded.  I would take another approach at it.

The main idea behind an infinite scroller is that you hold a subset of the items in memory, because fetching all of them is too expensive (in time, memory, etc).  Instead you fetch and display a subset, then when it looks like you need them soon, you fetch the rest.  Lets say that there's 1000 items to display.  You may only want to display the first 100 at the beginning.  So when you think you want to show the next 100 soon you start the fetch.  Like this:

```
bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
    if(position > getCount() - ITEM_FETCH_THRESHOLD && !fetching) {
        fetching = true;
        performFetch();
    }
}
```

performFetch should start an asynchronous fetch.  When the fetch finishes, it should call notifyDataSetChanged().  ITEM_FETCH_THRESHOLD is a constant that you can play with until you get right (the right value should be large enough that you can finish a fetch before it ends, but as small as possible to avoid overfetching).

That's all you need to do an infinite scroll.  There's some UI tweaks you can add in case the user hits the bottom before the fetch completes, but those are trivial to add.

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks for the answer Gabe, i will try to implement this now and then drop a message if i get it it working as well as marking your answer correct!

Comment: there maybe a problem. OnBindViewHolder gets called immediately for all items. I did a simple log to log out the position of each item. And the log for each item printed as soon as i opened the activity. Now, i implement your if statement, it will query the next batch of data, and then run onBindviewHolder automatically, and again, and again, without the user even scrolling once. It's basically performing 1 giant query, just in shorter intervals. But, the user first needs to scroll to the end, and then it should execute the performFetch()

Comment: bindViewHolder will only get called for onscreen items.  If you have it called for all items, you're doing something very weird and wrong elsewhere.

Comment: okay i see, currently, i only queried like 5 items, so thats why. I will up the item counts and get back to you

Comment: so there's a thing. In my query I get back 20 items (or 20 posts). And the recyclerview show items can handle all 20 times. So it will call onBindHolder on all 20 items right off the bat. It will not wait for the user to scroll down to the last item, which I can then call the performFetch() method